# Stein's proof Hilbert Spaces are complete

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Stein's ideia is simple: building a subsequence which converges and then proving the general Cauchy sequence converges too. To do this he defines $g$ to be equal to $g(x)=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty S_K(g)(x)}$ which he says converges almost everywhere. I do not understand why $g(x)$ would converge... It is clear from the highlighted section that the following limit exists though:

$$\lim \int_{\Omega} S_k^2(g)$$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series $g(x)$ converges almost everywhere as a simple consequence of the inequality $\int |g(x)|^2\,dx < \infty$.

The exercise that you should check is that if a nonnegative measurable function $F(x)$ satisfies $\int F(x)\,dx < \infty$, then $F(x) < \infty$ almost everywhere. For example, consider the sets $E_n = \{ x : F(x) > n\}$ and the set $\{ x : F(x) = \infty\} = \bigcap_n E_n$, as well as Tchebychev's inequality.